# Implementing algorithms from online courses in code to solidify understanding

Tags: coding-theory

I came across the online course [Design And Analysis Of Algorithms](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-046j-design-and-analysis-of-algorithms-spring-2015/pages/assignments/) and the assignments have several questions that ask you to design algorithms, but you are not asked to implement them in code. I think I would have a deeper understanding if I could see how to implement them in code, but there are questions covered on various topics such as network flows and linear programming that you would not find on websites like Leetcode or Codeforces where you could implement the code. Does anyone have suggestions on how you could implement the algorithms and similar to with Leetcode get some feedback on whether your implementation is correct and efficient?

Comment: For correctness you can compare your results to other pre-existing implementations

Answer (score 0):

For execution time, you just measure with problems of different sizes. Take a problem of size n big enough so it takes ten seconds to solve, then solve problems of size 1.1n, 1.2n and see how the time behaves.

Correctness: That’s a problem you will always have, in every programming job you do, when there is nobody to follow. Many problems produce a solution that can be checked. With optimisation problems, you can check that a solution is correct, checking that it is optimal can be difficult. Sometimes you have a fast and difficult, plus a slow and simple algorithm and can compare their outputs. And sometimes you can construct problem instances with a given solution.